# Why get-service is not able to list all services?

Tags: powershell, service

I'm experiencing an issue when trying to list all NFS services using the PowerShell Get-Service (gsv) command with a wildcard search. I noticed that the output is inconsistent when using the wildcard compared to specifying the service names directly. Here's the output I get:

```
PS C:\temp> gsv nfsrdr

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  nfsrdr             Client for NFS Redirector

PS C:\temp> gsv nfsclnt

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  nfsclnt            Client for NFS


PS C:\temp> gsv *nfs*

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  NfsClnt            Client for NFS


PS C:\temp>
```

As you can see, when I use the wildcard search (gsv *nfs*), it only shows one service (NfsClnt), while there are two services running on my system (nfsrdr and nfsclnt). However, when I run the following command, it can list both services:

```
PS C:\temp> gsv *nfs* -RequiredServices

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  NfsRdr             Client for NFS Redirector
Running  Tcpip              TCP/IP Protocol Driver


PS C:\temp>
```

Could anyone help me understand why Get-Service is not able to list all services by wildcard and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: The property **name** `Tcpip -notlike *nfs*` and [`RequiredServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service#-requiredservices)
Indicates that this cmdlet gets only the services that this service requires. This parameter gets the value of the **ServicesDependedOn** property of the service.

Answer (score -1):

Try this command

```
get-service -name nfs*
```

Comment: Please, add some explaination why that would make a difference to what is in the question.